# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I had an app that was working fine, but after updating to the latest version of flutter which is `2.8.1` it started showing errors regarding gradle files.

The error is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.6.0/core-1.6.0.aar
   > Could not find core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.6.0/core-1.6.0.aar
   > Could not find tracing-1.0.0.aar (androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/tracing/tracing/1.0.0/tracing-1.0.0.aar
   > Could not find versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.1.1/versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar
   > Could not find versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/versionedparcelable/versionedparcelable/1.1.1/versionedparcelable-1.1.1.aar
   > Could not find annotation-experimental-1.1.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation-experimental/1.1.0/annotation-experimental-1.1.0.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

As you can see android studio can't find some files online, but actually when I follow the links provided in the error, I can download these files but as a `.zip` format not `.aar`

Now usually when I encounter such errors I simply download the files manually and place them in their respective folders, which we can get to from the error it self, for instance:

if we took a look at the first file that is `core-1.6.0.aar` we can see that the folder of it is `androidx.core\core\1.6.0` and inside that folder android studio generates another folder with a random name like `7664385a7e39112b780baf8819ee880dcd3c4094`, so the full path is like so:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.core\core\1.6.0\<here goes the folder with the random name>
```

But for the files mentioned above android studio didn't generate any folders, so I have no idea what to do with them, where should I put them? or is there any way to resolve the error and get rid of it?

My `android\app\build.gradle` file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.bkh.pharmart"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

My `android\build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same problem . did you find any solution?

Comment: no, the workaround was to downgrade flutter

Comment: thank you . my brother . my flutter upgraded to 2.8 and I think my answer can you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue yesterday. and after 3 hours. I found a way .
close Android Studio and
remove `C:\Users\<USER>\.gradle` folder (or Rename it)

and Re Build Project with a Good VPN

I prefer VPN with `Cisco Any connect` Protocol .

---

this is my build.gradle and I add some repository may be it can help you.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it and tell you if it works for me too

Answer (score 0):

Update latest to the latest version of [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), then run

```
flutter clean 
flutter run
```